# how to assert a tuple in conditional

Tags: f#

Given the tuple:

```
let tuple = (true, 1)
```

How do i use this tuple in a conditional?
Something like this:

```
if tuple.first then //doesnt work
```

or

```
if x,_ = tuple then // doesnt work
```

I don't want to do this:

```
let isTrue value = 
   let b,_ = value
   b

if isTrue tuple then // boring
```

Is there a nice way to evaluate a tuple value inside a conditional without creating a seperate function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`fst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370480.aspx) function can help you out here.

> Return the first element of a tuple

An example:

```
let tuple = (true, 1)
if fst tuple then
    //whatever
```

There's also an [`snd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340353) for the second element.

Another alternative is to use [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx):

```
let tuple = (true, 1)

let value = 
    match tuple with
    | (true, _) -> "fst is True"
    | (false, _) -> "fst is False"

printfn "%s" value
```

This can let you match on more complex scenarios, a very powerful construct in F#. Take a look at the Tuple Pattern in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx#tuple) for a few examples.

Answer (score 3):

The function you are looking for is "fst".

```
let v = (true, 3)
if fst v then "yes" else "no"
```

"fst" will get the first half of a tuple.
"snd" will get the second half.

For additional information, the [MSDN has information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370480.aspx) function:

```
if tuple |> fst then
    ...
```